# How to test the redirected routes with zuul routes filters in zuulProxy

Tags: unit-testing, netflix-zuul

I am following this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611351/7103694

What I am missing is this part on how to mock the filter i had used for my zuul Proxy.

This is my error log.

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
...
Caused by: .com.demo.example.exception.AccessTokenMissingException: No access token found in request headers.
```

I have a custom prefilter to check for Authorization header.

```
public class PreRouteFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {


            RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
            HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
            String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

            // Check header if it contain AUTHORIZATION key and value starting with "Bearer "
            if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                ctx.set("error.status_code", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                throw new AccessTokenMissingException("No access token found in request headers.");
            }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I added my filter via this configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public PreRouteFilter routeFilter() {
        return new PreRouteFilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your test, you need to create a request and in that add a header for Bearer token based Authorization.
something like this,
1. create a RequestContext, -

`RequestContext context = new RequestContext();`

2. create a MockHttpServletRequest and add the Auth header to it.

```java
 MockHttpServletRequest httpRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
 httpRequest.setMethod("GET");
 String authHeader = "Bearer " + "your sample token string";
 httpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
 httpRequest.setRequestURI("/<whateverURI>");
```

3. set the Http request in the context,

```java
context.setRequest(httpRequest);
```

4. Set this context as the current test context,

```java
RequestContext.testSetCurrentContext(context);
```

5. Now, you can run the filter,

```java
yourFilter.run();
```